# Where and how should I handle multiple exceptions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

I have problem with handling exceptions. I know how to do it, but I'm not sure what's the correct place to rescue them. For example:

```
class ExampleService
  def call
    ...
    raise ExampleServiceError, 'ExampleService message'
  end
end

class SecondExampleService
  def call
    raise SecondExampleServiceError if something

    ExampleService.call
  rescue ExampleService::ExampleServiceError => e ---> should I rescue it here?
    raise SecondExampleServiceError, e.message
  end
end

Class ExampleController
  def update
    SecondExampleService.call
    
  rescue ExampleService::ExampleServiceError, SecondExampleService::SecondExampleServiceError => e
    render json: { error: e.message }
  end
end
```

As you can see in example I have two Services. `ExampleService` raises his own exception. `SecondExampleService` call the `ExampleService`, can raise exception and is used in `ExampleController`. Where should I rescue `ExampleServiceError`? In `ExampleController` or `SecondExampleService`? If in `ExampleController`, what about when we use such a Service in multiple controllers (rescue code will be repeated many times)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the controller only calls `SecondExampleService` directly and doesn't know anything about `ExampleService`, then it should not rescue from `ExampleServiceError`.

Only `SecondExampleService` knows that `ExampleService` is used internally, and therefore `SecondExampleService` should rescue from `ExampleServiceError` and translate it into a `SecondExampleServiceError`.

That is my interpretation of the [law of demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).